# Is there an ExoPlayer + Leanback library example for using captions?

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-tv, exoplayer2.x, amazon-fire-tv

I have found a few examples that work with `Leanback` and `ExoPlayer` and I have all that working but I can't get subtitles/captions to work. The newest Google example I could find (https://github.com/android/tv-samples) has a captions button on the Java sample but they never show up. The Kotlin example has a comment that says `// TODO(owahltinez): handle captions`.

I've tried these changes to one of the samples but it didn't help:

```
private void prepareMediaForPlaying(Uri mediaSourceUri) {
        String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(getActivity(), "VideoPlayerGlue");
        DefaultDataSourceFactory defaultDataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(getActivity(), userAgent);
        MediaSource mediaSource =
                new ExtractorMediaSource(
                        mediaSourceUri,
                        defaultDataSourceFactory,
                        new DefaultExtractorsFactory(),
                        null,
                        null);
        String subtitle = "https://subtitledomain/sintel-en.vtt";
        Uri uriSubtitle = Uri.parse(subtitle);
        MediaSource subtitleMediaSource = new SingleSampleMediaSource.Factory(defaultDataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(uriSubtitle, Format.createTextSampleFormat(null, MimeTypes.TEXT_VTT, C.SELECTION_FLAG_FORCED, "n/a"), C.TIME_UNSET);
        mediaSource = new MergingMediaSource(mediaSource, subtitleMediaSource);
        mPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
    }
```

And also this change:

```
    mTrackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
    DefaultTrackSelector.Parameters parameters = mTrackSelector.getParameters();
    mTrackSelector.setParameters(parameters.withSelectUndeterminedTextLanguage(true));
```

I've tried changing the language on the subtitle to `EN` and that didn't help. 
I feel like I'm probably just missing something small but I just don't know what it could be.

Thanks.

Edit: I made a branch and removed all `Leanback` code and just left `ExoPlayer` stuff untouched and used `com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView` in my `Fragment` instead of `VideoFragment` and subtitles worked without making any other change. So it is like I just need to enable them on the `Leanback` side somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get captions working you need to override lb_playback_fragment.xml and add a SubtitleView.

app/src/main/res/layout/lb_playback_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<!--
    Copied from android source so that we can add the subtitle view
-->
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/playback_fragment_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:transitionGroup="false"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.leanback.widget.NonOverlappingFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/playback_fragment_background"
        android:transitionGroup="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <androidx.leanback.widget.NonOverlappingFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/playback_controls_dock"
        android:transitionGroup="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SubtitleView
            android:id="@+id/leanback_subtitles"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Once this is done you can set up a DefaultTrackSelector to select the text track you want.

You can see the full code, based on the sample leanback player, in https://github.com/bennettpeter/android-MythTV-Leanfront. The change to add subtitles is in [this commit](https://github.com/bennettpeter/android-MythTV-Leanfront/commit/6966cfd16b06db5f8fd9b56bfd8fed04f276ccb5).

Comment: I cannot do that... i got error Cannot resolve androidx.leanback.widget.NonOverlappingFrameLayout because it is marked as @RestrictTo(LIBRARY_GROUP) and can only be called from within the same library group...

Comment: I have been using this for a couple of years and have not seen that problem. Does that error occur at compile time or run time? Perhaps you are using a different version from me?

Comment: this is happening in compile time. Im using latest stable release of leanback 1.0.0... i know there are 1.1rc and 1.2alpha, but they are not official releases so my company don't use them. And exoplayer 2.14.0.

Comment: And i've managed to insert SubtitleView programatically into this view, without need of overriding lb_playback_fragment.xml. i did it by creating my own new derived class of PlaybackSupportFragment and i created  new SubtitleView(requireContext()); added this to  root.addView(mSubtitleView, 0); and   finally had to add this line after exo intializations " val textComponent = exoplayer?.textComponent
                textComponent?.addTextOutput(subtitleView);"

Comment: If your error is reported against java code you may be able to prevent the error by adding @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi") in front of the function that is getting the error.

Comment: The error is within .xml files, so i cannot add any annotations.

Comment: I am also not able to override because of same problem

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach--renderIndex = 0 for video, =1 for audio, =2 for subtitles/text.

```
TrackGroupArray trackGroups = mappedTrackInfo.getTrackGroups(rendererIndex);   

TrackSelectionArray currentTrackGroups = player.getCurrentTrackSelections();
TrackSelection currentTrackSelection = currentTrackGroups.get(rendererIndex);


for (int groupIndex = 0; groupIndex < trackGroups.length; groupIndex++) {

    TrackGroup group = trackGroups.get(groupIndex);

    for (int trackIndex = 0; trackIndex < group.length; trackIndex++) {
        Format trackFormat = group.getFormat(trackIndex);


        if(currentTrackSelection!=null && 
          currentTrackSelection.getSelectedFormat()==trackFormat){
            //THIS ONE IS SELECTED
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: My issue isn't when setting the subtitles, if I take `Leanback` out then the subtitles work fine. I think the issue is telling the `Leanback` library to show the subtitle.